# Interpreted html tags

Tags: c#, html

I have developed a small windows forms application in C#.
This application simply manipulates data and then export it to 
html file.

But my problem is that some of the data that i'm exporting
includes html tags(,,). So this destroy the 
layout of my exported file(.html), because of this tags.

Is there a way to solve this problem ? Or is there an open source
reporting tool that can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: ............. i'm exporting includes html tags("<td>","<table>","<div>")............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the tags using entities: `&gt;` instead of `>`, `&lt;` instead of `<` and stuff like this.

Comment: How do implement this entities?

Comment: How do i implement this entities in this kind of example :

Comment: <html>
 <body>

 <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <table>
 <p>My first paragraph.</p>

 </body>
 </html>

Comment: <html>
 <body>
  "<table><tr><td> "+txtData.Text(contains -"</td><tr><td></td></tr><table>")+" </td></tr></table>"
 
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: Okay i managed to get it right. So a good example would be :  My name &lt;td&gt; = "My name <td>" . Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the html;

```
string inject = "<b>convert</b> me & £123 <br/>";
string safe = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(inject);

=== &lt;b&gt;convert&lt;/b&gt; me &amp; &#163;123 &lt;br/&gt;
```

Which will render in a browser looking just like `inject`.